# Get average of months over years

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find the average number of 'JOBS' in each month. i.e. What are the average jobs created in the month of May  (May 2011 + May 2012 + May 2013...May 2020), the month of June, etc.

```
NAME CLOSEDATE  JOBS  month year
A    2019-01-01 2     1     2019
B    2019-01-01 23    1     2019
C    2018-05-24 2     5     2018
D    2019-05-23 200   5     2019
E    2020-05-23 40    5     2020
F    2020-05-14 23    5     2020
G    2020-06-12 93    6     2020
```

I attempted:
`pd.pivot_table(proj, index=['month'],values=['JOBS'],aggfunc=[np.sum,np.mean])`
which gave me average jobs per record in the month, and not the average of the aggregate month.

In the sample dataset above ideally I'd get a result of 66.25 jobs for the month of May. (2+200+40+23)/4

I feel like I'm missing something simple, or a way to format the table as:

```
Year Jan   Feb   Mar ..... Dec
2011 1000  4322  5322      2343
2012 3423  4322  5322      2343
...  1645  4322  5322      2343
2020 7895  3432  9999      2343
AVG. 3491  4099  6491
```

Comment: Please the actual dataset used. The data you have given us is missing some of the columns you used. The question therefore lacks clarity

Comment: @RichieV that gets me almost to where I need to be, I changed to ```proj.groubpy([proj.CLOSEDATE.dt.year, proj.CLOSEDATE.dt.month]).sum().unstack()``` as mean gave me the average for all records

now I just need a row that shows the average of each column

Comment: @wwnde thanks for noticing, I realized in my simplification for the post that I had left out two columns from my calculation. I've edited for clarification.

Comment: @RichieV I'm struggling with words to describe. 
Pseudocode would be:

(All jobs in May2011 + All Jobs in May2012 + All Jobs in May2013)/(count of Mays) 
count of Mays in this case being 3
ie the average jobs created in all Mays combined. I feel like I'm overcomplicating somehow

Comment: @RichieV that's a disconnect on my end then, yes you are correct that is divided by years. which would be the same as number of Mays in my head, assuming that there is a May in all the years

Comment: @RichieV that would be the ideal world, yes

Comment: new = proj.groupby([proj['CLOSEDATE'].dt.year, proj.CLOSEDATE.dt.month]).sum().unstack()

new.mean()

essentially gets me the answer with the JOBS row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update

First get the sum for each year/month then average across years.

```
by_month = (
    proj.groupby([proj.CLOSEDATE.dt.year, proj.CLOSEDATE.dt.month]) # create the groupby object
    .JOBS.sum() # select only the JOBS column and aggregate by sum
    .unstack(0) # drop the 'year' level form MultiIndex and use as columns
    .mean(axis=1) # areage across the years we just unstacked to axis1
    .rename('avg_jobs')
    .rename_axis('month')
)

print(by_month)
month
1    25.000000
5    88.333333
6    93.000000
Name: avg_jobs, dtype: float64
```

---

This will get you the average jobs sum by month (accross years and names). Notice you can skip creating separate columns for year/month, only put them in if you want to keep using them for other calculations.

```
by_month = (
    proj.groupby('month') # create the groupby object
    .JOBS.mean() # select only the JOBS column and aggregate by mean
)

print(by_month)
month
1    12.50
5    66.25
6    93.00
Name: JOBS, dtype: float64
```

Comment: that was it! thanks for your patience and sticking with me through it

Comment: No problemo, look out for those caveats. It was hard for me when I jumped from excel to python because it is not as easy to see the data, you gotta keep a clear mental image of what you want to achieve and do thorough auditing of results